# Bean not being initialized when using jar file instead of sources

Tags: java, spring

I have a service that uses a self-written library. In the library, I use some Spring functionality and extend a bean post processor to allow for some custom configuration. The lib itself includes the Spring library as a compile dependency under gradle. This all looks as follows:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'org.stuff.library'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RELEASE'
    jacksonVersion = '2.9.6'
    lombokVersion = '1.16.18'
    jooqVersion = '3.11.2'
    flywayVersion = '5.1.3'
}

dependencies {

    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.22.0-GA'
    compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:${flywayVersion}"

    compileOnly "org.jooq:jooq:${jooqVersion}"
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"

    // other testCompile dependencies
}
```

*Bean extending the post processor:*

```
package org.stuff.library.config;

public class AnnotationTypePostProcessor extends AnnotationTypeBeanPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public AnnotationType postProcessAnnotation(AnnotationType original Annotation, Method annotatedMethod) {

  ... do some service-specific stuff
  return super.postProcessAnnotation();
  }
}
```

This bean is instantiated as follows:

```
@Bean(
    name = {SPRING_LIB_BEAN_NAME}
)
public static AnnotationTypeAnnotationBeanPostProcessor annotationTypeAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new AnnotationTypePostProcessor();
}
```

Upon start up, I issue a component scan through `org.stuff` which is the parent package of both my service and my library.

My issue is as follows:

1. If I include the sources of the library, my bean is picked up correctly and initialized. Afterwards, the Spring `BeanPostProcessor` correctly calls the extended class and thus my own method. The call for this looks as follows:

   ```
   private void doPostProcess(AnnotationType annotationType, Method method, Object bean) {
   annotationType = postProcessAnnotation(annotationType, method);
   ... Other stuff in Spring lib
   }
   ```
2. If I include a `.jar` file of my own library, the bean in my library configuration *is not initialized*, although the Configuration itself is initialized.

Why would this be happening? I scan the same packages with or without sources and the only libraries that the service it iself expected to bring are not Spring-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this was the following:

The class annotated with `@Configuration` that had the to-be-overriden bean declaration of type `AnnotationTypeAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` did not import the original Configuration class that declares the bean.

For some reason, it seems that Spring requires this to be explicitly set to override the beans when giving them by name. I could not find a reason for this.

To be clear, the solution was to change the configuration class declaration containing the overriden bean from:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig() {

@Bean(name = {SPRING_LIB_BEAN_NAME})
public static AnnotationTypeAnnotationBeanPostProcessor annotationTypeAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new AnnotationTypePostProcessor();
}
```

to:

```
@Configuration
@Import(OriginalConfigurationClassContainingBeanBelow.class)
public class SomeConfig() {

@Bean(name = {SPRING_LIB_BEAN_NAME})
public static AnnotationTypeAnnotationBeanPostProcessor annotationTypeAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new AnnotationTypePostProcessor();
}
```

After that, Spring always used the overidden bean.